# Consumer maximizing his total utility

Tags: economics, martingales

Consumer is trying to maximize his total utility if at a certain consuming amout:

a) marginal utility is equal to 0
b) marginal utility is equal to his total utility
c) marginal utility divided by price is equal to 0
d) marginal utility is maximal
e) marginal utility is equal to the price

Only one of these options is correct, which one is it? :-)

Comment: This has nothing to do with martingales. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Is this a question or a quiz?

Answer (score 1):

The maximum of $X$ is attained when marginal $X$ is $0$. Also known as "equate the derivative to zero". Hence,   (a) is correct. So is (c), for that matter.